# When trying to capture xpath of checkbox, ::before is getting highlighted, How do I capture xpath?

Tags: selenium, findelement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDnrV.png)

[enter image description here][3]

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='form-group field-user-terms required']/label").click()

I tried with the above xpath, instead of selecting checkbox. It is clicking on "Terms and conditions" link

Comment: There will be separate locator for checkbox., try to inspect the near by locator, i can no see the full `HTML` in screenshot, but you may try the this xpath  `//input[@type='checkbox']` to select the checkbox

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @id='user-terms']").click()

I tried this xpath, but it is throwing error as "element not interactable"

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='checkbox' and @id='user-terms']").click()

I tried with this xpath, but it is throwing error as "element not interactable"
I have attached the full html, Please check

Comment: I have added the answer, add the full `HTML`  for `element` if you still face the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting an implicit wait of maybe `10` seconds

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
```

**OR**

Set an explicit wait. An explicit waits is code you define to wait for a certain condition to occur before proceeding further in the code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "myXpath")))

element.click();
```

***OR***

```
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"yourXpath")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Haveyou tried copying the xpath of the line below the before::?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that is not working,  it is throwing error as "element not interactable"

Comment: @AmrithaRavikumar maybe by thr Id of that element?